# Javascript some() returns false on zero

Tags: javascript

I need to check if numbers exist in my array. Using the some() function I find that zero comes back false. It's a problem because I am working with a ton of different numbers and zero being one of them.

```
var array = [0, 1, 3, 4, 5];

var test = function(element) {
  return  0;
};

console.log(array.some(test));
// expected output: true on 0 <-- getting false
// expected output: true on 1
// expected output: false on 20
```

In short how can I get 0 to return true?

Comment: Your function always only returns `0`, a falsey value. The function is supposed to do whatever comparison you want, and return `true` or `false`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the test function always returns zero.

```
var test = function(element) {
  return  element == 0
};
```

This way the function should work properly.

The test function should return true/false.

In your case you always return 0 which is evaluated to boolean false.

Comment: use strict comparison operator, nl `element === 0`

Answer (score 3):

For what you're trying to implement, it might make more sense to use the `.includes` function, which tests whether an array includes a value:

```js
var array = [0, 1, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(array.includes(0));
console.log(array.includes(1));
console.log(array.includes(2));
```

Though, `.includes` (along with all array iteration methods) is an `O(N)` process - if you need to carry out a bunch of tests for the same array, you might convert the array to a `Set` first, so that you can then use `Set.has` (which is generally `O(1)`):

```js
var array = [0, 1, 3, 4, 5];
const set = new Set(array);
console.log(set.has(0));
console.log(set.has(1));
console.log(set.has(2));
```